# How to create URL with phone number for SIP call on pjsua util?

Tags: sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm trying to make a SIP call from PC to phone number over SIP server (sip.telnyx.eu) via pjsua cli utility. I can't solve correct syntax for it.

I've call *pjsua* util execution with config file and my setting. And looks like success to register on server but I can't make a call to specific phone number. My config file has the following structure:

```
--id sip:user@sip.telnyx.eu:port
--registrar sip:sip.telnyx.eu
--realm *
--username user
--password password
--add-budy sip:47-000-000-00@sip.telnyx.eu
```

So I'm not definitely sure that --add-budy should consist of specific phone number URL, but looks like this (please correct my case if it doesn't). I've wrong syntax on --add-budy. I can check it via

wrong

```
pjsua --add-budy sip:47-000-000-00@sip.telnyx.eu
pjsua_app_config.c !Argument "--add-budy" is not valid. Use --help to see help
```

wrong

```
pjsua --add-budy sip:4700000000@sip.telnyx.eu
pjsua_app_config.c !Argument "--add-budy" is not valid. Use --help to see help
```

wrong

```
pjsua --add-budy sip:47-00000000@sip.telnyx.eu
pjsua_app_config.c !Argument "--add-budy" is not valid. Use --help to see help
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found alternative solution. Need to past URL at the end of CLI args. Like this:

```
pjsua --config-file call.cfg sip:4700000000@sip.telnyx.eu
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the URI verification step is failing ; the message "is not valid" is explicit but unhelpful.

If it is not a bug (who knows!) then it is certainly a strict sip URI validation process so you should provide a conforming uri.

phone number mapping either tel or sip uri scheme:

`tel:47-000-000-00` or `sip:47-000-000-00@sip.telnyx.eu;user=phone`

a regular email style sip uri:

```
   sip:bob@biloxi.com
```

A enhanced uri with display name:

```
"Bob" <sip:bob@biloxi.com>
```